# after upgrade flutter to version 3, my exist project is not building

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

i was working on project using flutter 2.10.0 version, it work fine, but after upgrade flutter to 3.0.0 version, my project is not building, it give me this error

```
[        ] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug FAILED
[        ] Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[        ] Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[        ] See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[        ] 1 actionable task: 1 executed
[        ] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[        ] * Where:
[        ] Script '/home/user/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1156
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
[        ] > Process 'command '/home/user/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 18s
[ +550 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 5):

[This blog post](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-3-8c74a5bc32d0) might help you out:

> If you create a new project with the Flutter tool, you might notice that the generated files now use the latest versions of the Gradle and
> Android Gradle plugins. For existing projects, you need to manually
> bump the versions to 7.4 for Gradle, and 7.1.2 for the Android Gradle
> plugin.

Comment: After 5 hours finally I bumped into the correct answer. Thanks for sharing, +1 vote from me!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it updating 'build.gradle' from:

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
```

to

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4")
```

See more info in:

> https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#4-0-0

If the above does not fix the error try this:

After changing the following line:
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip` in

> android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Only need to change the version number.

Ran the following command:
`cd android` && `./gradlew clean`

Answer (score 2):

I tried the solution of [Kamrul Hasan Jony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72214504/8010101), but it always failed to build.

So the solution that worked for me is:

1. Created a new flutter project with the same `package name`
2. Update `pubsec.yaml` file with packages from old project
3. Update all changed files like `android/build.gradle`, `android/app/build.gradle`, `AndroidManifest.xml` ...

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after upgrading Flutter to version 3.17.0 and faced an issue. It turned out the problem was with the cached_network_image package, which I updated to the newest version (^3.3.0). Problem solved!